# How to repeat a function multiple times in python

Tags: python, function, repeat

I want to repeat a function multiple times like:

```
func(x) \  func(func(x))  \  func(func(func(x)))
```

I´ve tried multiple things like:

```
for x in range(1,11):
  func*x(value)
```

and it still doesn´t work, I hope you understand my problem, if I could be more specific please reply.

Comment: Are you expecting a recursion?

Answer (score 1):

```
#loop:
def func(a):
    return a + 1

x = 0
for a in range(3):
    x = func(x)
print(x)


# alternatively, recursion:
def func(a, depth):
    if depth>0:
        return func(a+1, depth-1)
    return a
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop:

```
def f(x):
    return x+2

x = 1
for _ in range(20):
    x = f(x)
    print(x)
```

Return the value from the function and call the function with the new value.

Output:

```
3
5
7
[...]
39
41
```

Use a list if you need all values:

```
def f(x):
    return x+2

x = [1]                  # initial value
for _ in range(20):
    x.append(f(x[-1]))   # feed it the last value from the list and append result

print(x)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41]
```